# mysql insert query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i have this page inserting data from html form. no error is showing but no data is inserted either. here is my code given.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hcp");

$queryUserType = "select * from user_type";
$resultUserType = mysql_query($queryUserType) or die(mysql_error());

$queryTitle = "select * from name_titles";
$resultTitle = mysql_query($queryTitle) or die(mysql_error());

$time = time();
$date = date("d-m-y");
$nowDateTime=$time.$date;

if($_REQUEST['btnUserSubmit'])
{
    $queryInsertUser="INSERT INTO  users (`title_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `utid`, `residence_address1`, `residence_address2`, `residence_city`, `residence_state`, `residence_country`, `residence_zipcode`, `phone_no`, `username`, `password`, `created`, `date_of_birth`, `gender` ) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['$rowTitle[0]'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtFirstName'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtLastName'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtEmail'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rowUserType[0]'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtAddressLine1'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtAddressLine2'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtCity'])."', '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtState'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtCountry'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtPhone'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtUserName'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtUserPassword'])."', '".$nowDateTime."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['txtdateofbirth'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rdGender'])."');";

$resultinsert=mysql_query($queryInsertUser) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

i don;t have any problem where the page redirected. Form validation is still remaining. in this table, only email,utid,username,password this four fields are NOT NULL. remaining are Null allowed.

Comment: Would help us / you, to print the contents of the INSERT request once it has been globbed.

Comment: place this in top of your script `error_reporting(1);` and check if it gives any error

Comment: My head hurts just trying to read this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**As you can see, your missing field 11, see below :**

```
<?php
$QueryCol   = array('title_id',             // Field 1
                    'first_name',           // Field 2
                    'last_name',            // Field 3
                    'email',                // Field 4
                    'utid',                 // Field 5
                    'residence_address1',   // Field 6
                    'residence_address2',   // Field 7
                    'residence_city',       // Field 8
                    'residence_state',      // Field 9
                    'residence_country',    // Field 10
                    'residence_zipcode',    // Field 11
                    'phone_no',             // Field 12
                    'username',             // Field 13
                    'password',             // Field 14
                    'created',              // Field 15
                    'date_of_birth',        // Field 16
                    'gender');              // Field 17

$QueryData  = array((isset($_REQUEST[$rowTitle[0]])      ? $_REQUEST[$rowTitle[0]]          : null),    // Field 1
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtFirstName'])    ? $_REQUEST['txtFirstName']        : null),    // Field 2
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtLastName'])     ? $_REQUEST['txtLastName']         : null),    // Field 3
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtEmail'])        ? $_REQUEST['txtEmail']            : null),    // Field 4
                    (isset($_REQUEST[$rowUserType[0]])   ? $_REQUEST[$rowUserType[0]]       : null),    // Field 5
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtAddressLine1']) ? $_REQUEST['txtAddressLine1']     : null),    // Field 6
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtAddressLine2']) ? $_REQUEST['txtAddressLine2']     : null),    // Field 7
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtCity'])         ? $_REQUEST['txtCity']             : null),    // Field 8
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtState'])        ? $_REQUEST['txtState']            : null),    // Field 9
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtCountry'])      ? $_REQUEST['txtCountry']          : null),    // Field 10
                                                                                                        // Field 11
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtPhone'])        ? $_REQUEST['txtPhone']            : null),    // Field 12
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtUserName'])     ? $_REQUEST['txtUserName']         : null),    // Field 13
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtUserPassword']) ? $_REQUEST['txtUserPassword']     : null),    // Field 14
                    $nowDateTime,                                                                       // Field 15
                    (isset($_REQUEST['txtdateofbirth'])  ? $_REQUEST['txtdateofbirth']      : null),    // Field 16
                    (isset($_REQUEST['rdGender'])        ? $_REQUEST['rdGender']            : null);    // Field 17

foreach($QueryData as $Key => $Value){
    $QueryData[$Key] = mysql_real_escape_string($Value);
}

$QueryInsertUser    =   'INSERT INTO users (`'.implode('`, `', $QueryCol).'`)'.
                        'VALUES ("'.implode('", "', $QueryData).'")';
$resultinsert       =   mysql_query($QueryInsertUser)
                        or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

**Tips :**

1. Stop using $_REQUEST. Either use $_GET or $_POST
2. Avoid using large line like you did. You cannot find an error quickly.
3. Use array to write less code.
4. Use [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php) function to map a function to every entry inside an array.
5. Make your code sweet to read, easier to debug
6. Variable like that `$_REQUEST['$Blabla']` won't work because using ' doesn't work for parsing variable, use " instead like that `$_REQUEST["{$Blabla}"]`. But, avoid that because PHP need to parse mean more power horse needed, use `$_REQUEST[$Blabla]` instead.
7. While developing, I recommend the following lines at the top of your script :

   ```
   error_reporting(-1);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   ```

   It will display all errors. Even the one that aren't really error. It will help you to write perfect code and standard code that'll work everywhere.
8. For every $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_FILES, etc. use the function [isset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) because it will generate an error.
9. Remember, every error double the time to load the page. Try to create a page with let's say 10000 rows with no errror, the average may be 0.01 second. With an error on each row, it may take 0.5 second. Watch that.

Comment: @Gerep Thanks, I just took time to do it. By default, this should be done while writing the code so it's very easy to debug and it's way faster. Also, you avoid stupid mistake like missing , ; ) ( or whatever. BUT, I will recommend using PDO, safer and faster to write. Require less debuging also.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBélanger. Your each tip is a lesson to me. but yet not i am done. i am facing this    "Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given in C:\wamp\www\HCP\login.php on line 59" ?

Comment: @decoyer Try my update. Also don't forget to add the missing field 11 (zip code)

Comment: missing field is added. but still saying : "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"... i have a primery key 'id'. which is auto incremented. is it causing problem?

Comment: @decoyer No. Are you sure all of your fields exists with the right name ?

Comment: yes. i have checked it quiet well. but...

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried changing

```
if($_REQUEST['btnUserSubmit'])
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['btnUserSubmit']))
```

?

EDIT!

I think also at the end of your INSERT query

```
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rdGender'])."');";
```

U can replace with:

```
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rdGender'])."')"; // Lose the ; after "')
```

Why dont you just use $_POST[];  instead of $_REQUEST[]; ?

Comment: The ; at the end is optional. See : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html `A command normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a semicolon. (There are some exceptions where a semicolon may be omitted. QUIT, mentioned earlier, is one of them. We'll get to others later.)`

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the first semi-colon at the end of the line so it reads as such:

```
...($_REQUEST['rdGender'])."')";
```